# New to SQL - Need help with a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1: Food

```
id name
-------
1 Hot-dog
2 Sandwich
3 Apple
```

Table 2: Report

```
id food_id date
----------------
1     1    2010-01-01
2     1    2010-02-01
3     2    2011-02-01
```

How can I devise a query to select all the food in the food table with a variable called numReports which is a total count of all reports that food item has in reports?

What I've been trying:

```
SELECT 
    food.id AS foodId, 
    food.name AS foodName,
    count(
        SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reports.food_id=food.id
        ) AS numReports
FROM 
    food
```

Output:

```
id name numReports
-------------------
1 Hot-dog  2
2 Sandwich 1
3 Apple    0
```

Comment: almost right, just move the `Count` inside the sub select.

Comment: Referred to your answer for help, thanks. Why would people choose to use INNER JOIN versus the way we have done it?

Comment: I don't really know, its easier to write with sub query (as we have) as you don't have to specify all the group by columns (can be many) and if you don't group on a primary key the sub query will have better performance.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT food.name,
       COUNT(*) as food_count
  FROM reports 
       INNER JOIN food ON reports.food_id = food.id
  GROUP BY food.name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using GROUP BY.

```
SELECT     food.id AS foodId,
           food.name As foodName,
           Count(*) AS numReports
FROM       food
INNER JOIN reports
ON         food.id = reports.food_id
GROUP BY   food.id,
           food.name
```

You could also use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT     food.id AS foodId,
           food.name As foodName,
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM reports WHERE food.id = reports.food_id) AS numReports
FROM       food
```

Comment: That's the optimization I was looking for...new groupby was the right tree to bark up ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    food.id AS foodId, 
    food.name AS foodName,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reports WHERE reports.food_id = food.id)
FROM 
    food
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be an optimized way to do this but here's one query that should get your results

```
select 
  food.id, 
  food.name,
  reports.reportcount
from 
  food
inner join
  (select 
    food_id, 
    count(food_id) reportcount
    from 
      report
    group by (food_id)) as reports
on food.id=reports.food_id
```